# No Member Named Reverse While Using reverse()

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, reverse, stdvector

```
    class Solution {
public:
    
    void print (vector<int> array)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
        {
            cout<<array[i]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    vector<int> nsr(vector<int> heights)
    {
        int n = heights.size();
        vector<int> v(n);
        stack <pair<int,int>> s;  
        
        for (int i=0 ;i<n;i++)
        {
            if (s.size()== 0)
            {
                v.push_back(-1);
            }
            
            else if (s.size()>0 && s.top().first<= heights[i])
            {
                v.push_back (s.top().second);
            }
            
            else if (s.size()>0 && s.top().first >=heights[i])
                
            {
                while (s.size()>0 && s.top().first>= heights[i])
                {
                    s.pop();
                }
                
                if (s.size() == 0)
                    v.push_back(-1);
                else 
                    v.push_back (s.top().second);
            }
                
            s.push({heights[i], i});
        }
     
        return v ;  
    }
    
    vector<int> nsl(vector<int> heights)
    {
 
        int n = heights.size();
        vector<int> v(n);
        print(v);
        stack <pair<int,int>> s;  
        
        for (int i=n-1; i>=0;i--)
        {
            if (s.size()== 0)
            {
                v.push_back(n);
            }
            
            else if (s.size()>0 && s.top().first<= heights[i])
            {  
                v.push_back (s.top().second);
            }
            
            else if (s.size()>0 && s.top().first >=heights[i])
            {
                while (s.size()>0 && s.top().first>= heights[i])
                {
                    s.pop();
                }
                
                if (s.size()== 0)
                    v.push_back(n);
                else 
                    v.push_back (s.top().second);
              
            }
            
            s.push({heights[i], i});
            
        }
       // print (v);
        return v;
  
    }
   
    int largestRectangleArea(vector<int>& heights) {
        
        vector<int> width ;
      
        vector <int> left= nsl(heights);
        left.reverse(left.begin(),left.end());

        vector <int> right = nsr(heights);
        
       // print(left);
       // print(right);
        
        for (int i = 0 ;i< heights.size()-1;i++)
        {
            int element = left[i] - right[i] - 1;
            width.push_back (element);
        }
        
        int area = INT_MIN;
        for (int i =0 ;i<heights.size()-1;i++)
        {
      
            int newarea = heights[i]* width[i];
            area = max(area, newarea);
            //cout<< area <<endl;
            
        }
        
        return area ;
        

        
    }
};
```

I am using reverse() in vector but it's showing an error. I have tried using header files but the error is same. I had used reverse with vector many times but it never gave an error.

**Error :**

*Line 80: Char 14: error: no member named 'reverse' in 'std::vector<int, std::allocator>'
left.reverse(left.begin(),left.end());*

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: there is no member `reverse` in `std::vector`. You probably used `std::reverse` before

Comment: Used std::vector , working fine now

Comment: but  reverse(a.begin(), a.end()); worked for me earlier

Comment: you are expected to do a minimum of research before posting the question. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: @Shroud You did not treat is as a member when it worked, and there was a `using namespace std;` so you could write "reverse" rather than "std::reverse". Perhaps it's time to review some basics in [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: `left.reverse(left.begin(),left.end());` and `reverse(left.begin(),left.end());` are not the same code at all.

Comment: Minor point: in that `if ... else if` ladder you don't need to keep testing `s.size() > 0`; you already know that that's true, because if it wasn't, the first branch (`if (s.size() == 0)`) would have been selected. Also, if `s.top().first <= heights[i]` is true, the third branch won't be reached. Really, the tests just need to be `if (s.size() == 0) ... else if (s.size() <= heights[i]) ... else ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no member function `reverse` in the class template `std::vector`. So this statement

```
left.reverse(left.begin(),left.end());
```

is invalid.

You should use the standard algorithm `std::reverse` declared in the header `<algorithm>` as for example

```
reverse(left.begin(),left.end());
```

There are other problems with your code.

For example in this declaration

```
vector <int> right = right(heights);
```

the declared identifier `right` hides a function `right` used as an initializer expression. (I suppose that in the right side there is used a call of a function with the name `right`.) That is in the both sides there is used the vector `right`. So the declaration does not make a sense.

If you mean the vector `right` in the both sides then just write

```
vector<int> right(heights);
```

Or it is unclear where the name `element` used in this for loop

```
for (int i = 0 ;i< heigths.size()-1;i++)
{
    element = left[i] - rigth[i] - 1;
    width.push_back (element);
}
```

is declared.

Or for example this for loop

```
for (int i =0 ;i<heights.size()-1;i++)
{
    int area = INT_MIN;
    int newarea = heights[i]* width[i];
    area = max(area, newarea);
    
}
```

does not find the maximum area.

And moreover outside the loop the name `area` used in the return statement

```
return area ;
```

is undefined.

You need to revise your code entirely from the very beginning.

Comment: I have fixed the code but now the problem is vector makes its size double unnecessarily which results in the wrong output. The extra indices contain zero creating problems in the output. I can fix this but it might again create problems in the future. I have allocated vectors size of height array which is enough. There is no extra space required at run time. Why it makes size double ?

Comment: @Shroud You should restore the original code and close the question selecting the best answer. Otherwise the question and answers will confuse readers. If you have a new problem then ask a new question after closing this question.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thank you will make new post for other issue.

Comment: could you please answer regarding vector as there is limit on asking question

Comment: @Shroud Which vector in which function?

Comment: @Shroud It seems you mean the following          int n = heights.size();
        vector<int> v(n); . After these lines the vector v is enlarged using the method push_back.  It seems you need not initially to set the number of elements in the vector v equal to n. It seems all elements should be created in the vector using the method push_back.